# __construct() must be an instance of App\CandidateProfile, int given

Tags: laravel

I'm queueing and dispatching a job to handle video uploads to s3.
A candidate creates a profile, he can upload a resume (required), profile photo and up to three videos (these are optional).
Everything works in my store method, now I'm trying to do the same thing for my update method, but I keep getting this error when I click update.

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\UploadVideos::__construct() must be an instance of App\CandidateProfile, int given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/highrjobsadminlte/app/Http/Controllers/CandidateProfileController.php on line 244
```

Job\UploadVideos.php:

```
protected $candidateprofile;
public $timeout = 120;
public $tries = 5;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @param CandidateProfile $candidateProfile
 */
public function __construct(CandidateProfile $candidateProfile)
{
    $this->candidateprofile = $candidateProfile;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
 */
public function handle()
{
    $disk = $this->candidateprofile->disk;
    $VideoOneFilename = 'videos/' . $this->candidateprofile->video_one;
    $VideoTwoFilename = 'videos/' . $this->candidateprofile->video_two;
    $VideoThreeFilename = 'videos/' . $this->candidateprofile->video_three;

    // Video One
    if(Storage::disk($disk)
        ->put($VideoOneFilename, Storage::disk('tmp')->get($VideoOneFilename), 'public')) {
        Storage::disk('tmp')->delete($VideoOneFilename);
    }

    // Video Two
    if(Storage::disk($disk)
        ->put($VideoTwoFilename, Storage::disk('tmp')->get($VideoTwoFilename), 'public')) {
        Storage::disk('tmp')->delete($VideoTwoFilename);
    }

    // Video Three
    if(Storage::disk($disk)
        ->put($VideoThreeFilename, Storage::disk('tmp')->get($VideoThreeFilename), 'public')) {
        Storage::disk('tmp')->delete($VideoThreeFilename);
    }

    // Update the database record with successful flag
    $this->candidateprofile->update([
        'upload_successful' => true
    ]);

}
```

CandidateProfileController.php:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

if($request->hasFile('video_one') && $request->hasFile('video_two') && $request->hasFile('video_three') && $request->hasFile('photo') && $request->hasFile('resume')) {
    $request->validate([
        'video_one' => 'file|max:30720',
        'video_two' => 'file|max:30720',
        'video_three' => 'file|max:30720',
        'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg',
        'resume' => 'file|max:10240',
        'job_title' => 'required',
    ]);
}

$candidateProfile = new CandidateProfile();
$candidateProfile->job_title = $request->job_title;
$candidateProfile->employment_type = $request->employment_type;
$candidateProfile->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
$candidateProfile->experience = $request->experience;
$candidateProfile->skills = $request->skills;
$candidateProfile->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

if($candidateProfile = $request->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
    'job_title' => $request->job_title,
    'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
    'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth,
    'experience' => $request->experience,
    'skills' => $request->skills,
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
])) {

    // Profile photo
    if($file = $request->file('photo')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        // resize image and store on s3
        $image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($file)->resize(300, 300)->stream();
        $image = $image->__toString();

        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $s3->put('images/' . $name, $image, 'public');

        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'photo' => $name
        ]);
    }

    // Resume
    if($file = $request->file('resume')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('resumes', $name, 's3');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'resume' => $name
        ]);
    }

    // Video One
    if($file = $request->file('video_one')) {
        $file_path = $file->getPathname();
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('videos', $name, 'tmp');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'video_one' => $name
        ]);
    }

    // Video Two
    if($file = $request->file('video_two')) {
        $file_path = $file->getPathname();
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('videos', $name, 'tmp');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'video_two' => $name
        ]);
    }

    // Video Three
    if($file = $request->file('video_three')) {
        $file_path = $file->getPathname();
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('videos', $name, 'tmp');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'video_three' => $name
        ]);
    }

    // dispatch a job to handle the image manipulation
    $this->dispatch(new UploadVideos($candidateProfile));

    return response()->json($candidateProfile, 200);
} else {
    return response()->json($candidateProfile, 500);
}

}
```

Comment: This line: `$candidateProfile = $request->user()->candidateprofile()->update([ ... ])`; `->update()` returns an integer, so doing this: `$this->dispatch(new UploadVideos($candidateProfile));` is invalid.

Comment: Since that's in an `if()`, I think you can just do `if($request->user()->candidateprofile()->update([...])){ ... }`, i.e. remove the assignment, and your code should work :)

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] so that we don't have to read through pages of unrelated code to see your problem. Also, be sure to read the error message carefully, it actually contains quite a lot of information about where your problem is.

Comment: I knew where the error was coming from, I just forgot that update() method returns a number, I guess 0 or 1 for true or false if it's successful. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating $candidateProfile outside the if() and as a suggestion, I have refactored your method code to split up functionality in smaller protected methods on the controller.

Good naming convention for such methods make the flow of execution within the controller very clear like saveProfilePhoto(), saveResume(), checkPresenceAndSaveVideo - I prefer it this way so just a suggestion.

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if(
        $request->hasFile('video_one') && 
        $request->hasFile('video_two') && 
        $request->hasFile('video_three') && 
        $request->hasFile('photo') && 
        $request->hasFile('resume')
    ) {
        $request->validate([
            'video_one' => 'file|max:30720',
            'video_two' => 'file|max:30720',
            'video_three' => 'file|max:30720',
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg',
            'resume' => 'file|max:10240',
            'job_title' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    $candidateProfile = auth()->user()->candidateprofile;

    //This below code seems redundant - to be removed
    //$candidateProfile = new CandidateProfile();
    //$candidateProfile->job_title = $request->job_title;
    //$candidateProfile->employment_type = $request->employment_type;
    //$candidateProfile->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
    //$candidateProfile->experience = $request->experience;
    //$candidateProfile->skills = $request->skills;
    //$candidateProfile->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if($request->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
        'job_title' => $request->job_title,
        'employment_type' => $request->employment_type,
        'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth,
        'experience' => $request->experience,
        'skills' => $request->skills,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ])) {

        // Profile photo
        $this->saveProfilePhoto($request);

        // Resume
        $this->saveResume($request);

        // Video(s)
        foreach(['video_one', 'video_two', 'video_three'] as $attribute) {
            $this->checkPresenceAndSaveVideo($attribute, $request);
        }

    
        // dispatch a job to handle the image manipulation
        $this->dispatch(new UploadVideos($candidateProfile->fresh()));

        return response()->json($candidateProfile->fresh(), 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json($candidateProfile->fresh(), 500);
    }
}


protected function saveProfilePhoto(Request $request)
{
    if($file = $request->file('photo')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        // resize image and store on s3
        $image = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($file)->resize(300, 300)->stream();
        $image = $image->__toString();

        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $s3->put('images/' . $name, $image, 'public');

        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'photo' => $name
        ]);
    }
}


protected function saveResume(Request $request)
{
    if($file = $request->file('resume')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('resumes', $name, 's3');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            'resume' => $name
        ]);
    }

}

protected function checkPresenceAndSaveVideo(string $attribute, Request $request)
{
    if($file = $request->file($attribute)) {
        $file_path = $file->getPathname();
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

        $file->storePubliclyAs('videos', $name, 'tmp');
        auth()->user()->candidateprofile()->update([
            $attribute => $name
        ]);
    }
}
```

Further Challange faced by the OP

> When I update only one or two videos (instead of all three at the same time), the Job fails and it shows this error message: League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path: videos/1606944108Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4

**Solution by OP @RyanSacks**
For reference of subsequent visitors

```php
protected function checkPresenceAndDeleteVideo(string $attribute, Request $request) 
{ 
    if($file = $request->file($attribute)) { 
        $filename = CandidateProfile::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->value($attribute);
 
        $disk = auth()->user()->candidateprofile->disk;

        Storage::Disk($disk) ->delete('videos/' . $filename); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is great. I was trying to think of a good way to refactor it. I like splitting up a long method into smaller methods with good naming conventions as you've done. Thank you very much!

Comment: There's one bug. When I update only one or two videos (instead of all three at the same time), the Job fails and it shows this error message:
League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path: videos/1606944108Pexels-Videos-1181911-copy.mp4
Any idea? I think because if I Upload video one and two, it still runs video_three in that method, in my Job/UploadVideos.php file. But the file won't be in the public disk because after I upload it to s3, I delete it. And I think that's what's causing the File not found error.

Comment: Quite possible. Can you handle deletion in a different method say by firing an event once you receive some confirmation that the file is properly uploaded to s3?

Comment: I actually solved it.
I created a new method called checkPresenceAndDeleteVideo right before checkPresenceAndSaveVideo (with the foreach), very similar.
protected function checkPresenceAndDeleteVideo(string $attribute, Request $request)
    {
        if($file = $request->file($attribute)) {

            $filename = CandidateProfile::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->value($attribute);

            $disk = auth()->user()->candidateprofile->disk;
            Storage::Disk($disk)
                ->delete('videos/' . $filename);

        }
    }
This is working!

Comment: @RyanSacks have included the solution in the answer with due credit to you as reference for subsequent visitors

Comment: I'm trying to now delete the videos from the tmp Disk, which for me is in storage/videos folder. The way my system is setup is the files get uploaded to the tmp Disk, and then moved over to s3. Once the job is completed or successful, I want to delete the files from the tmp Disk. I've tried deleting the files, before the job, after the job and inside the Job/UploadVideos.php file. No matter what I try, the job ends up failing and I get a File not found error. Let me know if you have any ideas here.